# Timestamp on certain terminal output

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a C++ file that outputs some terminal commands. I have the bash script to add a timestamp (ts) to each line but I wanted to know if it is possible to only add a timestamp to specific terminal output.

For example, on a C++ file that prints out numbers 0-100 but says "Found a prime number!" I want the timestamp only on the lines that say "Found a prime number!".

Is this possible with sed or grep, or is it only possible if you know the pattern of when they show up (Like I want a timestamp only every 10 lines). If the latter is possible, then is there a way to get that as well? Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask] and look at existing questions that have been upvoted and answered for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by `ts`, you meant the `ts` command from `moreutils`, note that it's a short perl script that inserts timestamps at the start of every line.

You can easily inline it and adapt to only add the timestamp if the line matches a regex:

```
c++-program | perl -MPOSIX -pe '
  $_ = strftime("%FT%T%z ",localtime) . $_ if /prime number/i'
```

for instance.

Or `if $. % 10 == 1` to get a timestamp every 10 lines, starting with the first line.

Or combined: `if /prime number/i || $. % 10 == 1`

Here using `%FT%T%z` to get standard unambiguous timestamps such as `2022-05-26T17:56:34+0100`, but you can adapt to your preferred format (check the `strftime` man page for details).